# Build Failed because of Missing google app Id

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

I have seen this problem going round and I have tried downgrading the Google App Id and even tried upgrading it but nothing worked. I even checked for updates but still no luck. I am having this error where it is saying 'Missing Google App Id' when I have it implemented. Can someone help?

This is from the build.gradle(WeightTracker)

```js
dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

    }
```

This is from build.gradle(app)

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.4.1')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

This is the error I keep getting:

```js
Missing Google App Id. Please follow instructions on https://firebase.google.com/ to get a valid config file that contains a Google App Id
```